# Calculate number of eigenvalues in interval $[-2, 3>$ of matrix $A$ using Sylvesters law of inertia and $LDL^T$ decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lu-decomposition

I have a new one, and I am not sure about a few things. I hoped you might help me in understanding them.

### For matrix
$$ A=\left[
\begin{matrix} 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 6 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ \end{matrix} \right] $$
Using Sylvester's law of inertia and $LDL^T$ decomposition find number of eigenvalues of matrix $A$ in the interval $[-2, 3>$. Determine and sketch the location of the eigenvalues using Gerschgorin theorem. Are you able to refine the results of the Gerschgorin theorem considering properties of the matrix $A$. Explain.

Sylvesters law of inertia (from what I understand of it, I am by no means close to an expert), claims that signs of the diagonal elements of the $D$ matrix will be identical to the signs of the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

First, I introduced $\lambda$ as eigenvalue.

$$ A=A-\lambda I=\left[\begin{matrix} 4-\lambda & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 6-\lambda & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{matrix} \right] $$

Second, I performed partial pivoting, in order to perform $LU$ decomposition of the matrix $A$.

$$ PA=LU $$

$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{matrix} \right] 
 \left[ \begin{matrix} 4-\lambda & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 6-\lambda & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1-\lambda \\ \end{matrix} 
 \right]
=
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1-\frac14 \lambda & -1+\frac54 \lambda-\frac18 \lambda^2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
4 & 6-\lambda & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 1-\lambda \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac18 \lambda^3+{11\over8}\lambda^2-{14\over8}\lambda-1 \end{matrix} \right] $$
From here, I used diagonal elements of the matrix $U$ to create matrix $D$, and matrix $L$ stays the same.
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac18 \lambda^3+{11\over8}\lambda^2-{14\over8}\lambda-1 \end{matrix} \right] $$
Of course, I immediately checked if $A=LDL^T$ is true, and it held true.

From here, I recognized one third degree polynomial, and found null points of that polynomial:
$$-\frac18 \lambda^3+{11\over8}\lambda^2-{14\over8}\lambda-1=0 $$
Solving this equation yields the eigenvalues of $A$
$$\lambda_1 = -0.424429$$  $$\lambda_2 = 2$$  $$\lambda_3 = 9.42443$$
Finally, I can say that two of the eigenvalues lie in the defined interval$[-2,3>$, but I am not certain if I was supposed to actually calculate the eigenvalues and compare the to the interval, or there exists a check that I can perform using Sylvester's law of inertia and $LDL^T$ decomposition.

Second part of the question is to use Gerschgorin theorem to determine and sketch the location of the eigenvalues. I created three disks, with centers on real axis, coordinates 4, 6, and 1, and assigned them radii 4, 6 and 2, , as can be seen on the picture. Red circles represent Gerschgorin disks, and black dots represent calculated eigenvalues.
[image: Gerschgorin disk theory]

I do not know how to refine the results. The matrix $A$ is hermitian, symmetric and indefinite, from what I can see, but I do not know how can this help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the outcome I commented about. You should repeat this task for $H+2I$ and $H-3I.$ I think starting from there is necessary as $P^TP$ is likely not diagonal.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

====================

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Out comes for $H+2I, H-2I, H-3I.$ The middle one confirms that $2$  is an exact eigenvalue of $h$ itself

H+2I

$$ P^T (H+2I) P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 8 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 16 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

H-2I

$$ P^T (H-2I) P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 4 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

H-3I

$$ P^T (H-3I) P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 8 }{ 13 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 3 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 4 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 22 }{ 13 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Dear Will Jagy,

Ti took me a few hours today, but I finally understood how to solve this, and literally came to confirm that indeed, algorithm you described is what I needed to solve my task.

Comment: @Geux the one difference from what they are calling LDL is that this way, if the $H$ has some entries zero on the diagonal, the final $P$ is not quite upper triangular. Try the matrix with all $0$ on the diagonal and all other entries $1,$ perhaps 3 by 3.

Comment: @Geux $$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Once I (or in this case, you) find $D$ matrices for $H+2I$ and $H-3I$, all that is necessary is to count number of nul and + signs in each matrix, as per Sylvester's law of inertia, and subtract two numbers to arrive at conclusion. I will try to write this mathematically, please forgive me:
$$ n^{H+2I}=sign_+[D^{H+2I}]+sign_0[D^{H+2I}], n^{H-3I}=sign_+[D^{H-3I}]+sign_0[D^{H-3I}]$$
$$n^{[-2,3>}=n^{H+2I}-n^{H-3I}$$
Where $n^{[-2,3>}$ is the number of eigenvalues in the interval $[-2, 3>$, and $ n^{H+2I}$ is the number of positive or zero eigenvalues for $H+2I$ matrix.

Comment: I will try, thank you.